# Nginx or javascript block specific external request file from being loaded within iframe

Tags: javascript, php, nginx, block, blacklist

Im am wondering if it is possible to block an external file like jquery from being loaded on my server. For example if an iframe tries to load jquery it will destroy my other stuff so maybe it is possible to use a 403 on that specific file request from external site not just my own. Thank you in advance

Comment: The jquery gets loaded inside the ifrane and should not destroy your other stuff

Comment: it was an example, another example would be to block a css file that the iframe is requesting. Is there a way?

Comment: css wont destroy your site too i think.

Comment: generaly you can't block iframes from requesting resources. But you can ofc modify the content of the iframe with javascript if cross origin is allowed.